# git bash always asking for github login

Tags: git, github, version-control

Every time i try to push a commit, git always pops up a login window for github as such

[image]

When I click cancel the push command runs as usual though but with a message `logon failed use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt`

[image]

I am logged in already on git bash (this issue only started a few weeks back), before then this prompt never showed up
The prompt only shows up when the remote is a git repository, pushing to another remote doesnt pop the prompt up

I have generated SSH keys and the public key file has been uploaded to github already and confirmed my account as authenticated yet the problem persists.
I have also tried multlple articles and nothing changes still
I am basically tired of having to click cancel every time I try to push changes, all help is appreciated

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the solution exists here: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases

Comment: I have followed the procedure on that page, ssh-agent is confirmed to be running as a process but i still get the prompt

Comment: I know what `git` is, and I know what `bash` is, but I don't know what `git bash` is. Could explain? It looks like you're asking about `git push`, bu you say *I am already logged in on git bash* and I'm not sure what to make of that.

Comment: @Caleb https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git-bash/info, https://gitforwindows.org/, https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-bash

Comment: @Caleb I meant I had already logged in github using the git CLI

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno Please note that the existence of an answer on an external site is *not* a valid reason to close a question.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the last-but-one white line in the output, you will notice that the git clone has been done with `https`. Instead of that, if you use the `git` protocol, this issue (repetitive prompt) will not happen.

Since you have already cloned the repo, you can just edit the `.git/config` file from within that git repo folder, and adjust the url to follow the `git` protocol format.

Comment: It always pops up regardless of the repo am pushing from

Comment: changing from https to git protocol says ```fatal: remote error You cant push to git://github.com/juniorbuba/weather-forecast.git```

Comment: Are you sure your ssh keys are registered? This "you can't push" message will only come if your auth has not been positive. Do you have any conflicting/overriding settings in your `~/.ssh/config` file? That might explain why a different ssh key is being used (than the one that's registered for this login in github)

Comment: the ssh key i used for authentication is confirmed already on github, i ensure the ssh agent is running in the background whenver i want to push but nothing changes and the config file looks just fine

Comment: In my setup, in my `~/.ssh/config` file, the contents are like this:
```
 Host github.com
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<name of ssh key file>
```